# How to structure a CV when applying for a Computer Science PhD?

Tags: phd, application, cv, industry

I am applying for a PhD in computer science. I have some research experience (from my Masters degree) as well as significant industry experience. I have been in industry for close to 4 years since my masters degree. I am targeting Software Engineering, so I believe my work experience will be relevant.

Now, universities require applicants to submit a CV. My current CV lists all work experience in reverse chronological order followed by education in reverse chronological order.

- How should I structure a CV when applying for a PhD in computer science?
- Should I  put the education before work experience?
- Any other tips?

Comment: Remember to number things starting from 0.

Comment: See also [how to write a CV for a phd application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56140/how-to-write-a-cv-for-a-phd-application?rq=1)

Comment: Some additional related questions: 1) [Should I mention industrial experience in an academic CV when applying for a PhD?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/57414); 2) [Which non-academic projects/experiences to mention in a PhD application?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/67879)

Answer (score 4):

I most often see CS CVs with education, then work experience, in reverse chronological order; followed by projects and publications. But the order is not really important, because in committee we jump around in the document anyway.

What is important for a PhD application, is to have a good presentation of projects the applicant has worked on, including bachelors and masters theses, and internships, because these are the unique bits that **make the difference between two candidates** with equivalent diplomas.

It is also very important to **not mix accepted publications with submitted manuscripts**. I have seen otherwise excellent applications excluded without debate because of this, without asking whether it was dishonesty or a simple mistake.

Beyond that, the European 
[Europass europa.eu website](https://europass.cedefop.europa.eu) has [CV templates and guidelines](https://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/documents/curriculum-vitae/templates-instructions/templates/doc) as well as online tools for building application-related documents. The CV template contains

1. Personal information
2. Position applied for
3. Work experience
4. Education and training
5. Personal Skills
6. Additional information

   - Publications, communications
   - Awards
   - Projects
   - Certifications, Memberships, References, etc